# De qual classe a classe texto deve herdar?

Tags: python, pygame

Ao utilizar o pygame é muito comum que classes do usuário herdem de classes do pygame, por exemplo uma classe de personagens geralmente vaqi extender a classe pygame.sprite.Sprite. Mas e uma classe texto poderia herdar de qual classe do pygame?

Comment: Creio que vá te ajudar: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html ; quando terminar a leitura, pode postar a resposta que ajudará outras pessoas também =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe uma "receita" de qual classe herdar. Você é que sabe o que sua classe vai ter que "saber" fazer, e se é apropriado que ela herde de alguma outra classe ou não.

O que sua classe texto vai ter como funcionalidade? Se ela for uma facilidade para exibir texto na tela, tendo atributos de fonte, cor, talvez posicionando automaticamente o texto e quebrando em linhas, ela pode não herdar de nenhuma outra classe.

Até faria sentido uma classe dessas herdar de pygame.Surface - por que isso permitiria que você atualizasse o seu conteúdo, e já usasse o seu próprio objeto da classe "Texto" como parâemtro para um "blit" e estampar o texto na tela. Só que infelizmente as Surfaces do pygame não se dão bem com herança: não adianta herdar a classe Surface, por que a sua sub-classe não vai funcionar como parâmetro para o blit em outra Surface, e ter métodos como "get_at" que funcionem. (Isso é um defeito do próprio Pygame)

Sendo assim, faz sentido, por exemplo, sua classe "Texto" ter um método "update" que re-cria uma surface com os parâmetros de fonte e mensagem configurados, e um método "draw" que faz o blit da mesma na tela.

Agora, perceba que nada impede que a sua classe texto seja ela mesma uma "sprite" - nesse caso, se ela tiver o método "update", o atributo "rect", e um atributo "image" que seja justamente uma Surface com o texto renderizado, ela pode pertencer a um grupo de sprites e o texto vai ser desenhado na tela pelo mesmo mecanismo que seus outros objetos de jogo.

Resumindo: 
Ou não herde de nada, e faça toda a funcionalidade você mesmo, ou herde de pygame.sprite.Sprite mesmo.

Comment: Essa resposta implicitamente considera que o código está em Python 3. Se por acaso você estiver em Python 2, deve sempre herdar de `object`. (Mas tente usar Python 3 para projetos novos)